# Using Python to dig into pixabay JSON response but my end result is duplicated

Tags: python, json, api

I'm using Python to grab some JSON from the [Pixabay API](http://pixabay.com/api/docs/). Here's what I've got:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://pixabay.com/api/?username=USERNAME&key=APIKEY&search_term=yellow+flower&image_type=photo&per_page=8')
r = r.json()
for i in r:
    for item in r['hits']:
        print item['type']
```

The results in the item['type'] are coming back, not 8 times like requested in the URL, but 16 times. After inspecting this several times over, I realized that my result was being duplicated in the for loops. The json coming back from the API has the correct number of results, 8. Printing the results of the first for loop, before the nested for loop, again shows 8 results. So what's wrong with my second for loop?

Is there a better way to do this?

Here's part of the raw json requests:

```
{
    totalHits: 240,
    hits: [
        {
            previewHeight: 99,
            likes: 17,
            tags: "flower, yellow, spehel",
            model_release: false,
            webformatHeight: 423,
            views: 3743,
            webformatWidth: 640,
            previewWidth: 150,
            comments: 5,
            downloads: 3148,
            pageURL: "http://pixabay.com/en/flower-yellow-spehel-144486/",
            previewURL: "http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/10/18/13/flower-144486_150.jpg",
            webformatURL: "http://pixabay.com/get/ed740e2b05f6d3677fc8/1389429953/8ecd2717750798bd3f896e9b_640.jpg",
            imageWidth: 4928,
            user: "corinaselberg",
            type: "photo",
            id: 144486,
            imageHeight: 3264
        },
        {
            previewHeight: 84,
            likes: 5,
            tags: "flower, yellow, close",
            model_release: false,
            webformatHeight: 360,
            views: 2286,
            webformatWidth: 640,
            previewWidth: 150,
            comments: 2,
            downloads: 2092,
            pageURL: "http://pixabay.com/en/flower-yellow-close-195893/",
            previewURL: "http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/10/15/09/12/flower-195893_150.jpg",
            webformatURL: "http://pixabay.com/get/e26fb4e50bd3b145d905/1389429953/bf1a2065a9c9d042d1abdc6b_640.jpg",
            imageWidth: 4000,
            user: "Josch13",
            type: "photo",
            id: 195893,
            imageHeight: 2250
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but after a couple hours pounding away at this, I thought I'd ask here and see if anyone can spot my problem (with the code).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't run twice?  Is this the actual code?

Comment: Wait, why are you iterating over `r['hits']` in a loop over `r`? This doesn't sound right

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid; there must be quotes around the string names.

Comment: @MartijnPieters seems to be parsed just fine nevertheless.

Comment: @JanDvorak: This is a valid JavaScript structure, just not a valid JSON structure. You cannot parse what is posted here with `json.loads()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thus I'm surprised that `.json` parses it just fine. Most parsers are very strict...

Comment: @JanDvorak: No, `requests.json()` won't parse this either (that just uses the `json` library). What is posted here is not the actual raw JSON.

Comment: a reason to downvote the asker?

Comment: @JanDvorak: I did not vote on the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did, for an unrelated reason. In fact, I was suggesting you do or talk me out of my downvote.

Comment: @JanDvorak: ah, well, our votes are entirely our own. I got the gist from the posted sample and the question was clear enough to me. It included a clear description of what the unexpected output was and what the OP expected instead.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm curious to know why you downvoted. Was something wrong with the way I asked the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top-level object is a dictionary, but you are looping over that object, which means you are looping over the keys. Inside that loop you are looping over `r['hits']` too, repeating that loop for every key. The outer dictionary has 2 keys, so you are repeating your `r['hits']` loop twice.

The outer loop is entirely redundant, remove it:

```
r = requests.get('http://pixabay.com/api/?username=USERNAME&key=APIKEY&search_term=yellow+flower&image_type=photo&per_page=8')
r = r.json()
for item in r['hits']:
    print item['type']
```

Comment: For some reason when I was first going over the JSON response I was unable to get ['hits'] to pull anything up which I thought was because the result was a list containing a dictionary and I was trying to get the internal dictionaries key. That's why I did the whole nested loop thing. Backing out and going over the response just once did the trick, thanks for the help!